# finding matrix through optimisation

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra, blas, colormatrix

I am looking for algorithm to solve the following problem :

I have two sets of vectors, and I want to find the matrix that best approximate the transformation from the input vectors to the output vectors.

vectors are 3x1, so matrix is 3x3.

This is the general problem. My particular problem is I have a set of RGB colors, and another set that contains the desired color. I am trying to find an RGB to RGB transformation that would give me colors closer to the desired ones.

There is correspondence between the input and output vectors, so computing an error function that should be minimized is the easy part. But how can I minimize this function ?

Comment: Do you have correspondence between the vectors in the two sets (i.e. is set 1, vector 1 supposed to map to set 2, vector 1)?

Comment: Is this some kind of gamma correction? or histogram mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify a language, but here's how I would approach the problem in Matlab.

- v1 is a 3xn matrix, containing your input colors in vertical vectors
- v2 is also a 3xn matrix containing your output colors

You want to solve the system

```
M*v1 = v2
M = v2*inv(v1)
```

However, v1 is not directly invertible, since it's not a square matrix. Matlab will solve this automatically with the mrdivide operation (M = v2/v1), where M is the best fit solution.

```
eg: 
>> v1 = rand(3,10);
>> M = rand(3,3);
>> v2 = M * v1;
>> v2/v1 - M

ans =

   1.0e-15 *

    0.4510    0.4441   -0.5551
    0.2220    0.1388   -0.3331
    0.4441    0.2220   -0.4441

>> (v2 + randn(size(v2))*0.1)/v1 - M
ans =

    0.0598   -0.1961    0.0931
   -0.1684    0.0509    0.1465
   -0.0931   -0.0009    0.0213
```

[This](http://kybele.psych.cornell.edu/~edelman/Course/lightness/node23.html) gives a more language-agnostic solution on how to solve the problem.

Comment: That would be great, I am working on static data, so I can give a shot at matlab

Comment: Accepted because of the link, that helped me searching and discovering good explanation about this problem.

Answer (score 6):

This is a classic linear algebra problem, the key phrase to search on is "multiple linear regression".

I've had to code some variation of this many times over the years.  For example, code to calibrate a digitizer tablet or stylus touch-screen uses the same math.

---

Here's the math:

Let **p** be an input vector and **q** the corresponding output vector.

The transformation you want is a 3x3 matrix; call it **A**.

For a single input and output vector **p** and **q**, there is an error vector **e**

**e** = **q** - **A** x **p**

The square of the magnitude of the error is a scalar value:

**e**T x **e** = (**q** - **A** x **p**)T x (**q** - **A** x **p**)

(where the T operator is transpose).

What you really want to minimize is the sum of **e** values over the sets:

**E** = sum (**e**)

This minimum satisfies the matrix equation **D** = 0 where

**D**(i,j) = the partial derivative of **E** with respect to **A**(i,j)

Say you have N input and output vectors.

Your set of input 3-vectors is a 3xN matrix; call this matrix **P**.
The ith column of **P** is the ith input vector.

So is the set of output 3-vectors; call this matrix **Q**.

When you grind thru all of the algebra, the solution is

**A** = **Q** x **P**T x (**P** x **P**T) ^-1

(where ^-1 is the inverse operator -- sorry about no superscripts or subscripts)

---

Here's the algorithm:

Create the 3xN matrix **P** from the set of input vectors.

Create the 3xN matrix **Q** from the set of output vectors.

Matrix Multiply  **R** = **P** x transpose (**P**)

Compute the inverseof **R**

Matrix Multiply **A** = **Q** x transpose(**P**) x inverse (**R**)

using the matrix multiplication and matrix inversion routines of your linear algebra library of choice.

---

**However**, a 3x3 affine transform matrix is capable of scaling and rotating the input vectors, but **not** doing any translation!  This might not be general enough for your problem.  It's usually a good idea to append a "1" on the end of each of the 3-vectors to make then a 4-vector, and look for the best 3x4 transform matrix that minimizes the error.  This can't hurt; it can only lead to a better fit of the data.

Comment: This is a great answer too, but explanation were better (stackoverflow is not great for math) in the link I discovered in Kena's answer. So Kena got the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Some linear algebra should be enough :

Write the average squared difference between inputs and outputs ( the sum of the squares of each difference between each input and output value ). I assume this as definition of "best approximate"

This is a quadratic function of your 9 unknown matrix coefficients.

To minimize it, derive it with respect to each of them.

You will get a linear system of 9 equations you have to solve to get the solution ( unique or a space variety depending on the input set )

When the difference function is not quadratic, you can do the same but you have to use an iterative method to solve the equation system.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you asked for a description of the maths

Answer (score 1):

This answer is better for beginners in my opinion:

Have the following scenario:

[image]

We don't know the matrix M, but we know the vector I<sub>n</sub> and a corresponding output vector O<sub>n</sub>. n can range from 3 and up.

If we had 3 input vectors and 3 output vectors (for 3x3 matrix), we could precisely compute the  coefficients α<sub>r;c</sub>. This way we would have a fully specified system.

But we have more than 3 vectors and thus we have an overdetermined system of equations.

Let's write down these equations. Say that we have these vectors:
[image]

We know, that to get the vector O<sub>n</sub>, we must perform matrix multiplication with vector I<sub>n</sub>.
In other words: **M** · I̅<sub>n</sub> = O̅<sub>n</sub>
If we expand this operation, we get (normal equations):
[image]

We do not know the alphas, but we know all the rest. In fact, there are 9 unknowns, but 12 equations. This is why the system is overdetermined. There are more equations than unknowns. We will approximate the unknowns using all the equations, and we will use the sum of squares to aggregate more equations into less unknowns.

So we will combine the above equations into a matrix form:

[image]
And with some least squares algebra magic (regression), we can solve for b̅:
[image]
This is what is happening behind that formula:
Transposing a matrix and multiplying it with its non-transposed part creates a square matrix, reduced to lower dimension ([12x9] · [9x12] = [9x9]).
Inverse of this result allows us to solve for b̅.
Multiplying vector y̅ with transposed x reduces the y̅ vector into lower [1x9] dimension. Then, by multiplying [9x9] inverse with [1x9] vector we solved the system for b̅.

Now, we take the [1x9] result vector and create a matrix from it. This is our approximated transformation matrix.

A python code:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg

INPUTS  = [[5,6,2],[1,7,3],[2,6,5],[1,7,5]]
OUTPUTS = [[3,7,1],[3,7,1],[3,7,2],[3,7,2]]

def get_mat(inputs, outputs, entry_len):
    n_of_vectors = inputs.__len__()
    noe = n_of_vectors*entry_len# Number of equations
    #We need to construct the input matrix.
    #We need to linearize the matrix. SO we will flatten the matrix array such as [a11, a12, a21, a22]
    #So for each row we combine the row's variables with each input vector.
    X_mat = []
    for in_n in range(0, n_of_vectors): #For each input vector
        #populate all matrix flattened variables. for 2x2 matrix - 4 variables, for 3x3 - 9 variables and so on.
        base = 0
        for col_n in range(0, entry_len): #Each original unknown matrix's row must be matched to all entries in the input vector
            row = [0 for i in range(0, entry_len ** 2)]
            for entry in inputs[in_n]:
                row[base] = entry
                base+=1
            X_mat.append(row)
    Y_mat = [item for sublist in outputs for item in sublist]

    X_np = np.array(X_mat)
    Y_np = np.array([Y_mat]).T
    solution = np.dot(np.dot(numpy.linalg.inv(np.dot(X_np.T,X_np)),X_np.T),Y_np)
    var_mat = solution.reshape(entry_len, entry_len) #create square matrix
    return var_mat


transf_mat = get_mat(INPUTS, OUTPUTS, 3) #3 means 3x3 matrix, and in/out vector size 3
print(transf_mat)
for i in range(0,INPUTS.__len__()):
    o = np.dot(transf_mat, np.array([INPUTS[i]]).T)
    print(f"{INPUTS[i]} x [M] = {o.T} ({OUTPUTS[i]})")
```

The output is as such:

```
[[ 0.13654096  0.35890767  0.09530002]
 [ 0.31859558  0.83745124  0.22236671]
 [ 0.08322497 -0.0526658   0.4417611 ]]
[5, 6, 2] x [M] = [[3.02675088 7.06241873 0.98365224]] ([3, 7, 1])
[1, 7, 3] x [M] = [[2.93479472 6.84785436 1.03984767]] ([3, 7, 1])
[2, 6, 5] x [M] = [[2.90302805 6.77373212 2.05926064]] ([3, 7, 2])
[1, 7, 5] x [M] = [[3.12539476 7.29258778 1.92336987]] ([3, 7, 2])
```

You can see, that it took all the specified inputs, got the transformed outputs and matched the outputs to the reference vectors. The results are not precise, since we have an approximation from the overspecified system. If we used INPUT and OUTPUT with only 3 vectors, the result would be exact.